# Sass Loader Error: Invalid options object. Stylus Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli, stylus

I'm getting this error after running npm run serve:

```
in ./src/components/site-checker/insert-model.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=stylus&

Syntax Error: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Stylus Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'preferPathResolver'. These properties are valid:
   object { stylusOptions?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter?, additionalData? }
```

---

I'm using VueJS with this framework:

[Vue 2] babel, router, vuex
Vue CLI v4.5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of a recent compatibility issue between `stylus-loader` and `vue-cli`.  It was recently [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/6130) in Vue's dev branch.

The best bet for now is to downgrade `stylus-loader` to version 3

```
npm install stylus-loader@3
```

You can also try upgrading your `vue-cli` to the latest version:

> npm update -g @vue/cli
>
> OR
>
> yarn global upgrade --latest @vue/cli

Comment: And  I made "vue.config.js" file next to "package.json" file.

<pre>
--------------------------------
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: "stylus-loader", // compiles Styl to CSS
      },
    ],
  },
};
----------------------------------
</pre>

Comment: I'm using   
 `
stylus-loader@4.3.1
    + stylus@0.54.8
 `

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I'm still  getting same error after running   npm run serve

Comment: I did create a brand new app.  
But I got same error after running npm run serve.  
so,I downgrade  stylus-loader to version 3.
Then the error disappeared.